# Mostrar datos de un bucle en Python con Kivy

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica, kivy

Me encuentro haciendo un pequeño script que, mediante una función devuelva una serie de números que luego quiero visualizar. Dispongo de una función *contador()* que devuelve una variable a la que he llamado *numbers* y se trata de un diccionario tal que así:

> numbers = {"DW": 0, "IW": 0, "RW": 0, "DR": 0, "IR": 0, "RR": 0}

Ahora bien. Esta función hace bien su trabajo; he usado print() para ver los datos que devolvía por consola y no hay problema alguno. Mi duda ahora viene cuando intento usar Kivy para mostrar estos datos en una pequeña ventana en lugar de usar la consola.

Después de instalar Kivy y probar que funciona (está importado y ya he hecho un pequeño test que prueba que está funcionando sin problema), me dispongo a hacer que Kivy muestre los valores de *numbers* pero no lo consigo.

```
# Creo una clase Interfaz con Kivy:
class Interfaz(App):
  def build(self):
    return Label("Little test")

Interfaz().run()
```

Mi idea, es meter esto dentro del bucle de ejecución de mi programa ya que debe llamarse a la función *contador()* cada minuto para que actualice los valores:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   while True:

      dicc = contador()
      # Aquí debería pasarle los valores de contador() (almacenados en dicc) a la interfaz.

      time.sleep(60)
```

He probado a meter la declaración de la clase Interfaz() dentro del propio *while* del main pero me da error:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

   DW = 0

   class Interfaz(App):
     def build(self):
       return Label(DW)

   while True:

      dicc = contador()
      DW = dicc["DW"]

      time.sleep(60)
```

> TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

¿Cómo puedo hacer para pasarle los datos a Kivy según se vayan actualizando?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciclos infinitos y funciones bloqueantes como `input` o `time.sleep` son una idea muy mala en una GUI si se usan en el mismo hilo que ésta. Con ello consigues que el mainloop de la aplicación se bloquee, dejando de procesar eventos y dibujar la interfaz, congelándose y dejando de responder...

**Asumiendo que tu función no sea bloqueante** (retorne de forma inmediata) la solución la tienes en el caso de kivy en [`kivy.clock.Clock.shedule_interval()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) que permite de maneara asíncrona programar la ejecución de una callback cada `x` segundos.

Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import random

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


def contador():
    return {"DW": random.randint(0, 100),
            "IW": random.randint(0, 100),
            "RW": random.randint(0, 100),
            "DR": random.randint(0, 100),
            "IR": random.randint(0, 100),
            "RR": random.randint(0, 100)}


class Interfaz(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.dw_label = Label()
        self.add_widget(self.dw_label)
        self._update()
        self._sheduler = Clock.schedule_interval(self._update, 60)

    def _update(self, dt=None):
        d = contador()
        self.dw_label.text = (
            f'DW: {d["DW"]}\nIW: {d["IW"]}\nRW: {d["RW"]}\n'
            f'DR: {d["DR"]}\nIR: {d["IR"]}\nRR: {d["RR"]}\n'
            )


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Interfaz()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En este caso `contador` se limita a retornar un diccionario con los valores aleatorios.

**Si tu función contador fuera bloqueante, lo anterior no es suficiente** ya que bloquearíamos igualmente el mainlooop de la app desde que es llamada hasta que retorne. En este caso hay que **hacer la propia ejecución de la función de forma asíncrona** (y no solo el tiempo de espera entre llamadas). Para ello hay que recurrir a hilos, proceso, corrutinas, etc dependiendo del caso concreto.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, desconocía el uso de "Clock".